# Oracle 11g docker SELECT very slow

Tags: sql, performance, docker, oracle11g

I have an oracle 11g docker container ([using this docker image](https://github.com/wnameless/docker-oracle-xe-11g)).

When i try to execute `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ALL_OBJECTS`, it take about 100 seconds to return 7000.

On an other database (hard install), the same query return 62000 in 2 secondes

Why this query is too long on docker ?

Thanks.

Comment: i dont think it's the image fault because i'm using https://hub.docker.com/r/alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g/ (which is based on wnameless  just giving some more customization like mounting volumes) the select query are working just fine...
try looking up your cpu ram and disk usage when running query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

It seems that it's the image fault.
The tools that execute this query (DBunit in this case) has a mistake on it's configuration.

It query all DBobjects the schemas for the docker DB and only the specific shemas objects for the 'hard install' DB.

Answer (score 6):

This command helped me to resolve the slowness issue:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET disk_asynch_io = FALSE SCOPE = SPFILE;
```

You need to restart the db instance.